# Print with cups using exec() in php?

Tags: php, printing, server, cups

I want to print automatically a file after pressing a button on a page. So i installed cups on my small Raspberry Pi Apache server and created a code with PHP that looks like...

```
$path = "/media/usb/test.pdf";
$message = exec('sudo lp -d <<PrinterName>> $path');

echo $message;
```

(I replaced my `PrinterName`)

Now the job is send to cups, but the Status is "stopped". Also the size of the job is OK and the quantity of pages is 0.

I also tried to run the same command directly in the terminal (without variables) and everything worked.

Is this a problem with the permissions?

Comment: Does your Web server user have permission to execute the command? As if you use echo exec('whoami'); you'll notice a different user to what you'd run the actual terminal screen you create

Comment: Thanks for your answer! exec('whoami') shows me "www-data" and in the terminal it shows me "pi". Do i have to change to owner of the php file to pi (sudo chown pi:pi /var/www/test.php)? However if i do that exec('whoami') is still telling me "www-data" instead of "pi".

Comment: Just have a research for the permissions used by your command. Never give a script full administration permissions. That's asking for alot of pain

Comment: On a different note. You could run a Cronjob to execute the print command with information stored in the database.  That'll be the best approach

Answer (score 1):

If your command line works fine on Terminal with complete path but don't in PHP command line that means you have correct permissions to print your file.
So the problem comes from your syntax using **$path** within your command.

Using simple quotes instead of double quotes in PHP code when including a variable, doesn't display the content of the variable but the variable as a text.
 
Try this:

```
// Use
$message = exec("lp -d <<yourPrinter>> $path"); // This will display '/media/usb/test.pdf'
// instead of
$message = exec('lp -d <<yourPrinter>> $path'); // That will display '$path' (not correct)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the printer is not declared on the server from which you are launching the command.

You can check the printers with the command `lpstat -d`.